# Django - Template Tags, display <ul> - <li>

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I have a working model.py like this, I am able to add records to this model using Django admin:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from audiofield.fields import AudioField

# Create your models here.
class Music(models.Model):
    tittel = models.CharField(max_length=20, default = "titel her")
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=20, default = "Artist")
    cover = models.FileField("Cover", upload_to="player/cover/")
    audio = AudioField(upload_to='player/audio/', blank=True, ext_whitelist=(".mp3",".wav",".ogg"))
    is_active = models.BooleanField(("is active"), default = False)
    date_created = models.DateField(verbose_name="Created on date", auto_now_add="True")

class MusicAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('tittel', 'artist', 'cover', 'audio', 'is_active', 'date_created')
```

I want to display the records it in my index.html using template tags.
My music-app folder structure:

```
.
├── admin.py
├── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── templatetags
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── musikk_tags.py
├── tests.py
└── views.py
```

The music_tag.py:

```
from django import template
from music import models

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag
def get_music_tags():
    return models.Music.objects.all()
```

I am trying to use the template tags like this inside the index.html: (I only want the active records to display)

```
<ul class="playlist hidden">
    {% load musikk_tags %}
    {% get_musikk_tags as musikk %}
    {% if musikk.isactive %}

        <li audiourl="{{ musikk.audio.url }}" cover="{{musikk.cover.url}}" artist="{{musikk.artist}}">{{musikk.tittel}}</li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
```

I do not get any errors, but still no music is displayed. 
When not using the music-app, and hard coding the list like this:

```
<ul><li audiourl="01.mp3" cover="cover1.jpg" artist="Artist 1">01.mp3</li></ul>
```

Everything work as expected. There must be some kind of issue with the template tags. thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_music_tags` returns a queryset - a collection of (in this case) all Music objects. The queryset itself doesn't have `isactive`, `audio` or `cover` properties: only the individual items inside the queryset do. You need to iterate through them:

```
{% get_musikk_tags as all_musikk %}
{% for musikk in all_musikk %}
    {% if musikk.isactive %}

        <li audiourl="{{ musikk.audio.url }}" cover="{{musikk.cover.url}}" artist="{{musikk.artist}}">{{musikk.tittel}}</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem! (had to change isactive  to is_active)